# Copy data from desktop excel to onedrive excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, worksheet-function, vba

I need to copy data's from one desktop excel to one drive excel file by VBA. Is their any option works by VBA?

Like This I need to convert One drive excel source

```
Dim Iws as worksheet
Dim Ows as worksheet 'Need to set as one drive file
 Iws.range("A2:A35”).copy
Ows.range("A10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: No need to do so,,, just go with basic use SAVE AS and select the one drive ICON,, remember you must have Microsoft Account ID & PW since while this U will be prompted to Loggin !!

Comment: i need this for multiple users , if one user means that is okay.

Comment: You can reference an online workbook in a cell just like you do with a static file reference, e.g. `='[https://mycompany.org/examples.xlsx]sheet1'!A1`. A onedrive file should have a similar URL you can use, and I see no reason why it shouldn't also work in VBA.